# Field inside a spherical cavity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

[image]

A spherical portion has been removed from a solid sphere having a charge distributed uniformly in its volume. If at all a cavity is carved inside the sphere...will the field inside the cavity be equal to zero or will a field exist?

But my textbook says that the cavity will have a uniform electric field inside it. Can someone spot the error in my logic and correct me on this?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at answering this?

Comment: @Superfast Jellyfish   ya .. I just added an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If there is no charge inside a cavity , it not necessarily mean that the electric field is $0$,but you can say that according to gauss law, only the flux is zero .That ,means the field lines entering the cavity and leaving the outer surface of cavity  are same, even though the cavity may have electric field lines due to outside charges

2)Now charge enclosed inside cavity is $0$, but outside charges may create an electric field at interior of cavity, even though field due to inside charges is $0$ in this case

Comment: can you elaborate on your 2nd point further please

Comment: @Devaesh I meant to say that for electric field inside a cavity you  need to consider outside charges along with inside charges, but for flux you only need to consider enclosed charges (because  flux due to charge outside is $0$ as solid angle is $0$, but for electric field there is no need of solid angle)